# if / else "last resort" while in a loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

here is the scoop. I have a program that loops through an ArrayList and checks to see if the values are equal to an inputted keyword(`inputArray[0]`)

I want to add a default action incase `inputArray[0]` is not equal to any of the values inside of the `keyList`

The `else if` is where I am having the problem. I want my loop to go through ALL of the values in `keyList` before it resorts the "last resort" - an else statement. Right now my problem is that in the first if statement it sees that `inputArray[0]` is not equal to `keyList[x]` and it goes to the else statement without going through another run of the loop.

As you can see, I tried using an else if statement, where if my loop's counter, x, is larger than the size of keyList then it will do the code inside, but that seemingly does not work. I also added `continue;`to the else statement to ensure that it is going through the loop, which according to the console, it is. (I know because of the `System.out` statement at the beginning of the loop.)

```
public static void wikiInit(ArrayList keyList, ArrayList nameList, ArrayList domainList, ArrayList softwareList, String[] inputArray, EntityPlayer player)
{
    System.out.println("These are the current lists:");
    System.out.println("Key List: " + keyList);
    System.out.println("Name List: " + nameList);
    System.out.println("Domain List: " + domainList);
    System.out.println("Software List: " + softwareList);

    // KEY PARSER
    for(int x = 0; x < keyList.size(); x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting the loop");

            if((keyList.get(x)).equals(inputArray[0]))
            {
                //getWikiName = wikiNameArray[x]
                //getWikiDomain = wikiDomainArray[x]
                //getWikiSoftware = wikiSoftwareArray[x]

                StringBuilder hyperlinkBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int y = 1; y < inputArray.length; y++)
                    {
                        hyperlinkBuilder.append(inputArray[y] + " ");   
                    }
                        if((softwareList.get(x)).equals("MEDIAWIKI"))
                        {
                            String hyperlink = "http://" + domainList.get(x) + "/index.php?search=" + hyperlinkBuilder.toString();

                            System.out.println("Searching for " + hyperlinkBuilder.toString() + " on the " + nameList.get(x));
                            player.addChatMessage("Searching for " + hyperlinkBuilder.toString() + " on the " + nameList.get(x));


                              BrowserHandler.browserInit(hyperlink.replace(" ", "+"), player);
                              System.out.println("Opening " + hyperlink.replace(" ", "+"));
                              break;
                        }

            }
            else if(x > keyList.size())
            {//LAST RESORT

            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: wouldn't `if x+1 === keylist.size()` be a more accurate condition for your `else if`. Since x would never be greater than keylist.size

Comment: It would help if you can add some initialization data and the expected output. It's a bit confusing your description at the moment.

Comment: FYI - your `x > keyList.size()` will never be executed - the for loop would have exited first.

Comment: You want something to be done after the loop, but you put it inside the loop. BTW, the loop is guarded by `x < keyList.size()`, so, insidse the loop, you'll never have `x > keyList.size()`.

Comment: @CBIII I tried `x >= keyList.Size()` as well. It didn't work.

Comment: Maybe your loops are inside out? Sounds like you should array entry, you want to look at every key, and then if there is no match, go with your last resort.

Comment: I also want to correct my `===` meant to say `==` Too much javascript; @user2647089 it didn't work because x will never be >= keyList.size in that conditional statement. Hence why I gave you a valid condition. By the time x is == keylist.size the loop would terminate. The values of x for that conditional will only be 0 - keylist.size() - 1; You should take note of that even if you found a better answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of loop use

```
if(keyList.contains(inputArray[0])){
  int x = keyList.indexOf(inputArray[0]); 
  StringBuilder hyperlinkBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for(int y = 1; y < inputArray.length; y++)
    ...
}
else { // last resort code
}
```

Comment: I will try this. I didn't know I could use `.contains` like that.

Comment: If you are using `String` (or other language system types) or custom object with `equals/hashCode` redefined it works like a charm!

Comment: Note that this doesn't duplicate the original code in cases where the input value appears in the keyList more than once. Notice that the original code finds each matching one and tests whether it matches MEDIAWIKI. If it doesn't, it keeps looking in the keyList. Notice the break is inside the innermost `if`.

Answer (score 2):

If the default action should only happen after all elements have been checked, it should happen outside the loop.  You can do this by using a variable to signal when this happens:

```
boolean found = false;

for(int x = 0; x < keyList.size(); x++)
{
    System.out.println("Starting the loop");

        if((keyList.get(x)).equals(inputArray[0]))
        {
            found = true;
            ...
        }
}

if (!found) {
    //The value was never found, do something special.
}
```

Having said that, in this case it would be much easier to use `keyList.contains`, as in bellabax's answer.

Answer (score 1):

We usually do it like this where we search first and then put the code to handle the found one later.

I also lifted the one part out of the loop, since it didn't need to be in there. It could also go down in the "found" part of the code but I liked getting it out of the way to make the code more readable.

Also, the test for MEDIAWIKI is left in the loop (unlike my earlier version of this). Thanks to @paxdiablo for that. It is also a failing of some other answers here (as of right now).

```
StringBuilder hyperlinkBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // lift this out of the loop
for(int y = 1; y < inputArray.length; y++) {
    hyperlinkBuilder.append(inputArray[y] + " ");   
}

int found = -1;
for(int x = 0; x < keyList.size(); x++)
{
    System.out.println("Starting the inside of the loop");
    if((keyList.get(x)).equals(inputArray[0])) {
        if((softwareList.get(x)).equals("MEDIAWIKI"))
            found = x;
            break;
        } 
    }
}

if (found >= 0) {
    int x = found;

    //getWikiName = wikiNameArray[x]
    //getWikiDomain = wikiDomainArray[x]
    //getWikiSoftware = wikiSoftwareArray[x]

    String hyperlink = "http://" + domainList.get(x) + "/index.php?search=" + hyperlinkBuilder.toString();

    System.out.println("Searching for " + hyperlinkBuilder.toString() + " on the " + nameList.get(x));
    player.addChatMessage("Searching for " + hyperlinkBuilder.toString() + " on the " + nameList.get(x));

    BrowserHandler.browserInit(hyperlink.replace(" ", "+"), player);
    System.out.println("Opening " + hyperlink.replace(" ", "+"));
} else {
    //LAST RESORT ... fill in 'not found' code
}
```

Comment: That's not _quite_ the same unless you're certain there's no duplicates in the keylist. This will process only one whereas the original would have processed all. Granted, though, that's not likely to be the case.

Comment: @paxdiablo Good point. The original would have kept looking until it found a MEDIAWIKI one. Then it would have quit. No processing would happen for any others found.

Comment: @paxdiablo Fixed it according to your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply set a `found` variable to false before the loop and set it to true inside the loop if you find a key match.

Then after the loop:

```
if (!found)
    complainBitterly();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a boolean. Set it to false before the for loop, and if `inputArray[0]` is equal to `keyList[x]`, set the  boolean to true (in your if statement).

Then have an if statement after the for loop that will do your last case resort if the bool is still false.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is you can make this a lot simpler by making 2 changes.

First, extract those 4 separate lists that you reference and combine them as a list of objects with fields for each list, 'ParameterTuple`in the code.  Second, you can track loop exit status with another variable,`foundMediaWikiKey` in the code.

```
/**
 * Not sure of a better name for this class, you'll need to look at in the larger sense.
 * Also, in production you probably want to use getters for these, rather than final 
 * public and the constructor
 */
public class ParameterTuple {
    public ParameterTuple(String key, String name, String domain, String software) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        this.domain = domain;
        this.software = software;
    }

    public final String key;
    public final String name;
    public final String domain;
    public final String software;
}

public static void wikiInit(ArrayList<ParameterTuple> paramList, String[] inputArray, EntityPlayer player) {
    System.out.println("These are the current lists:");
    System.out.println("List: " + paramList);

    // Variable to keep track of how we exited the loop.
    boolean foundMediaWikiKey = false;

    // KEY PARSER
    for(ParameterTuple param : paramList)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting the loop");

        if(param.key.equals(inputArray[0])) {

            StringBuilder hyperlinkBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for(int y = 1; y < inputArray.length; y++) {
                hyperlinkBuilder.append(inputArray[y] + " ");   
            }

            if(param.software.equals("MEDIAWIKI")) {
                String hyperlink = "http://" + param.domain + "/index.php?search=" + hyperlinkBuilder.toString();

                System.out.println("Searching for " + hyperlinkBuilder.toString() + " on the " + param.name;
                player.addChatMessage("Searching for " + hyperlinkBuilder.toString() + " on the " + param.name;


                BrowserHandler.browserInit(hyperlink.replace(" ", "+"), player);
                System.out.println("Opening " + hyperlink.replace(" ", "+"));

                // Keep track of how we exited the loop
                foundMediaWikiKey = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // When we exit, check to see how we did so.
    if (!foundMediaWikiKey) {
        // Last Resort
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want my loop to go through ALL of the values in keyList before it
>   resorts the "last resort" - an else statement

```
            else if(some condition)
            {
                 if(x!=keylist.size()-1)      // USE IT HERE
                 { continue; }

                 //LAST RESORT

            }
```